# Bigquery Stored Procedure with SPARK

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery

I am testing the pyspark stored procedure new functionality in GCP Bigquery. I can run a simple example code without problems. But when I tried to use external dependencies like **names** it fails with the "ModuleNotFoundError No module named names"

I tried with the py_file_uris and the archives_uris with the dependencies into a zip file and nothing seems to works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
    `my_project.remote_functions.spark_proc`()
WITH CONNECTION `my_project.us.pyspark_connection` OPTIONS (engine='SPARK',
        runtime_version='2.1',
        main_file_uri='gs://pyspark_procedure/my-pyspark-main.py',
        py_file_uris=["gs://pyspark_procedure/spark_venv.zip"],
        properties=[])
    LANGUAGE python;
```

```
# main.py

import names
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Employees").getOrCreate()

    # define the schema for the DataFrame
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("employee_name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("department", StringType(), True)
    ])

    # create a list of rows with the data
    data = [
        Row(names.get_full_name(), "IT"),
        Row(names.get_full_name(), "HR"),
        Row(names.get_full_name(), "IT"),
        Row(names.get_full_name(), "HR")
    ]

    # create the DataFrame
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    df.show()
```

I am running out of Ideas, How Can I pass the dependencies to this procedure ? Thanks in advance.